# Static and Normal class combined in one class

Tags: static, c++-cli, unmanaged

I am trying my best to explain the situation. I hope, what I wrote, is understandable.
We already have class defined like

```
public ref class TestClass
{       
public:
        TestClass();
        virtual ~TestClass();
protected:              
        Car* m_car;

}
```

`TestClass` is managed C++ and `Car` is unmanaged C++.

So far so good, but now I need to make static object of `TestClass` also. So I modify the code like below

```
public ref class TestClass 
{
private:
    static  TestClass^  s_test = nullptr ;
public:
    TestClass();
    virtual ~TestClass();
    static TestClass^ Instance();
protected:              
    Car* m_car;
}
```

When I want to use static instant of the class, I just get it from calling

```
TestClass staticobj = TestClass::Instance();
```

Elsewhere, just call

```
TestClass normalobj = gcnew TestClass();
```

Instance function is creating `s_test` static object and returns it.

```
TestClass ^ TestClass::Instance() 
{
    if(s_test == nullptr)
    {
          s_test = gcnew TestClass();
          s_test->m_car = new Car();

    }       
    return s_test;
}
```

Is it a good approach? 
Is there any other better approach to accomplish same thing?

Edit :
FYI Above code works.

I combined Krizz and Reed Copsey’s solutions. That solve independent Singleton and memory leak.
Here is my sample code, 
Special Singleton class derived from test class,

```
    public ref class SpecialSingletonTestClass: public TestClass
        {
            private:
                static SpecialSingletonTestClass ^ s_ SpecialSingletonTestClass = nullptr;
             public:
                SpecialSingletonTestClass ();
                static SpecialSingletonTestClass ^ Instance();
        };
```

Changed the testclass so it has now one more finalizer function.

```
    public ref class TestClass 
    {
    public:
        TestClass ();
        virtual ~ TestClass ();
        ! TestClass ();
protected:              
         Car* m_car;

    }
```

I tested above pattern , it worked.

Thanks you guys,

L.E.

Comment: You are attempting to make a Singleton?

Comment: @crush . The class is already define i just need to get static object of it. Singleton means only one object of the class, but in this case, class have multiple normal object. But i want to use only one object of this class for one specific goal only for limited period of time.

Comment: And what is the problem or your anxiety about this code?

Comment: @Krizz i am not pro in handling unmanaged code and managed code. I freak out about memory leak. I want to know better approach for this. So far i got answer which are good.

Comment: Yes, memory leaks are things to worry about with unmanaged code, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually there is an issue with memory leaks in your code.

You declare only `virtual ~TestClass();` which, for managed classes, are internally turned by C++/CLI compiler into implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose()`.

Therefore, if you put `delete car` into it, it will be called only if you `delete test_class` or, e.g. wrap into `using (TestClass tst) {}` block when using from C#.

It will **not** be called when object is GCed!

To be sure it is called you need to add finalizer to your class `!MyClass();` which is turned by compiler into `virtual void Finalize()` and thus non-deterministically called when GC is freeing an object.

And it is the only way to free `m_car` of singleton object.

Therefore, I suggest:

```
TestClass()
{
    m_car = new Car();
}

~TestClass()
{
    if (m_car) 
        delete m_car;
    m_car = NULL;
}

!TestClass()
{
    if (m_car) 
        delete m_car;
    m_car = NULL;
}
```

Comment: This is another issue i was struggling with. Your code looks promising, but as  my brain processor is quite slow in unmanaged code. I am trying to see how i can combine @Reed Copsey's approach and your approach to get rid of memory leak and single case for class(either singleton or normal). Thanks for your code.

Comment: Just have both destructor and finalizer as described by me and then create another class `SpecialSingletonTestClass` that inherits from `TestClass` and put `SpecialSingletonTestClass^ getInstance()` and `s_test` there.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good approach?

I would probably not consider this a good approach, as you're making a single class both a singleton and a normal class that you can instance directly.

Typically, if you need a singleton, this would preclude the need or desire to be able to instantiate the class.

If you truly need to have a way to have a "global" instance of this class, I would encapsulate that in a separate class which implements the singleton.  This would, at least, make it clear that you are dealing with something that's a single instance in that case.  I would not mix both use cases into a single class.

Comment: not mixing both cases in a single class is correct. That might work but for that i have to create Singleton classes which use current class inside. which is not preferable in my case.

Comment: @L.E. That would be my approach, if you truly need a singleton instance.  Mixing this into the same class really confuses things horribly.  Maybe just have a separate class that has the single instance of your class in it (statically)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to what situation you could possibly be in that would require both singleton-style semantics and normal creation semantics for the same class.

As far as what you've coded though, it looks completely fine.  My only comments would be that your `Instance()` function shouldn't need to perform construction on `Car`, the `Instance()` function should just call the default constructor of `TestClass` which should do all that.

**EDIT**

In reference to:

@crush . The class is already define i just need to get static object of it. Singleton means only one object of the class, but in this case, class have multiple normal object. But i want to use only one object of this class for one specific goal only for limited period of time. – L.E. 2 mins ago

A singleton is (usually) a sign of bad design - alot of people call it an anti-pattern actually.  Chances are if you just need this one single specific instance of this class for a limited period of time there are some issues:

1. Singleton design is made for static-style existence - the variable will live for the scope of your program after lazily initialized.
2. Allowing global access will move your code towards spaghetti logic.  You'd be better off dynamically allocating the one you need and passing the pointer to it to where you need it to be.  A shared_ptr would be good for this.

You should find a way around the singleton-style implementation in this case even if it's more work for you - it'll almost certainly be better design.

Comment: Are you sure you can have such an instance of managed class and return it by reference? The question is about C++/CLI, not C++.

Comment: I have no idea honestly - I don't know managed C++ particularly as I said in the middle.  If you cant, you can still return a pointer to it though and make it pretty similar at least (I'd assume).

Comment: I don't think you can return pointer either. I guess the only option for managed class is a managed reference (denoted by `Type^`)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I too it out :)